TV show about evil clown/circus/carnival and a young boy trying to stop this evil
I can remember watching this show during the early 2000s. I think it was a kid show, even though I can remember it being quite dark.
All I can think of is that there was this evil clown/circus/carnival in this town and there was a young boy (maybe a teenager) that had to stop this evil. The bad guy lived in a basement (some sort of dark area) and it was always messy (it might've even been a dump). I can also remember a flying thing, possibly a bird....?
Sorry that I can't remember too much about this show, but I really want to find it!

Stephen King's It?

it parallels some aspects of an  supernatural episode

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

Most of myth and horror movies , parallels some aspects with one of supernatural episode.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

I am not at liberty to post this as an answer just now, but could it have been Something Wicked this way Comes?

It's been awhile since I last seen this movie, but from what I remember it sort of sounds like "Ghoulies 2". 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093091/?ref_=tt_rec_tt

it has a main character (a teenager) trying to stop evil creatures.
happens inside an amusement park
has a monster called "Bat Ghoulie/Flying Ghoulie" which might explain the flying thing. (http://littleghoulies.wikia.com/wiki/What_is_a_Ghoulie%3F)


Good job on providing a link to the resource, and also elaborating on why this meets the OP's requirements.

Sounds like Carnivàle, which ran on HBO for two seasons from 2003 to 2005

I was trying to look for this for years. I have finally found it. The show was called "Ace Lightning".

The series follows the life of British teenager Mark Hollander who moved to the American town Conestoga Hills with his parents. One stormy night, Mark plays his favourite video game, the fictional Ace Lightning and the Carnival of Doom - a superhero-based adventure game where hero Ace Lightning traverses the Carnival of Doom to find the pieces of the magical Amulet of Zoar, whilst battling his nemesis Lord Fear. Mark stumbles across a mysterious seventh level which is not meant to exist. A lightning bolt strikes the antenna on his roof, and through an electrical surge, the characters of the game come to life. Ace hires Mark as his sidekick to fulfil the game's objectives in the real world. Mark's life is turned upside-down, and his duty as a Lightning Knight effects his school grades and social life, often forcing him to make excuses to his family and friends. Meanwhile, Lord Fear's group of villains occupy the town's rundown Kent Bros. Carnival.

The flying creature might be Dirty Rat, a "winged rat dressed as a clown" who becomes the greater antagonist later in the season.



That's the first episode of the first season.

I think it might be Stephen King's IT. It was a TV miniseries that is sometimes shown as a film. 
Tim Curry plays the evil clown! 

Sounds like Texas Chainsaw 3D. It's a long shot, but there was a particular scene when Heather escapes and makes her way into a carnival, but Leatherface follows her carrying a chain saw. And by the way, this is a 2013 film.
